# Why does pandas remove duplicate data?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I pulled in some trade history from Binance and need to change the time column to a readable format. There are 203 columns and when running:

```
trades = client.get_my_trades(symbol='TRADINGPAIR')

trade_history = df(trades)

trade_history_time = trade_history['time']

final_time = []

for time in trade_history_time.unique():
    readable = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time/1000))
    final_time.append(readable)
```

I now get readable times but now there is only 160 lines. What can I add to the code above so it keeps all dates in the column?

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime` to convert the date strings.

Comment: Yes but the issue is columns are being removed. Will pd.to_datetime solve this?

Comment: Yes. You are iterating over `.unique()` instead of over the series. Doesn't look like all your dates are unique.